# Does the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality apply to integrals?

Tags: integration, vector-spaces

The integral $\int f(t) g(t) \, \mathrm{d} t$ is like the dot product $\vec{u} \cdot \vec{v}$.

The Cauchy-Schwartz inequality is

$$ \left\lvert \vec{u} \cdot \vec{v} \right \rvert \le \left\lvert u \right\rvert \left\lvert v \right\rvert$$

Is the following true?

$$ \left\lvert \int^b_a f(t) g(t) \, \mathrm{d} t \right \rvert \le \left\lvert \int^b_a f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t\right\rvert \left\lvert \int^b_a g(t) \, \mathrm{d} t \right\rvert$$

I'd imagine that if this works it only applies for very carefully defined functions such as smooth functions and only on finite intervals.

This could be useful for integral transforms:

$$ \left\lvert \int^b_a K(s, t) f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t \right \rvert \le \left\lvert \int^b_a K(s, t) \, \mathrm{d} t\right\rvert \left\lvert \int^b_a f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t \right\rvert$$

But I don't think this applies to most common generalized functions used for such transforms.

Comment: Yes this applies because Cauchy Schwarts is generally true in prehilbert spaces for any hilbert inner product.

Comment: By defining $\langle f, g\rangle = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx $ the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality holds in the same way. You first inequality has plenty of counter-examples like $(a,b)=(0,1)$ and $f(x)=g(x)=x$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does (although not in the way you stated):
$$\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f(x) \overline{g(x)}\,dx\right|^2 \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)|^2\,dx \cdot \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |g(x)|^2 \,dx.$$
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2

Answer (score 0):

For $L^2$ functions the C.-S. inequality holds true. Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set of $\mathbb{R}^n$, given $f,g \in L^2(\Omega)$ then
$$
\left | \int_{\Omega} f(x)g(x) \, dx \right | \leqslant \left \| f \right \|_{L^2(\Omega)}\left \| g \right \|_{L^2(\Omega)}
$$
The case of the integral transforms is a particular case, so that if $K(\cdot,t), f(t) \in L^2(a,b)$ then 
$$
\left | \int_{a}^{b} K(\cdot, t)f(t) \, dt \right | \leqslant \sqrt{\int_{a}^{b} K(\cdot, t)^2\, dt} \sqrt{\int_{a}^{b} f(t)^2 \, dt} 
$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f^2,g^2$ be summable ($ \int_{\Omega} f(x)^2 \, d\mu(x) < \infty $). Then
$$ 2\left( \int_{\Omega} f(x)^2 \, d\mu(x) \right) \left( \int_{\Omega} g(x)^2 \, d\mu(x) \right) - 2\left( \int_{\Omega} f(x)g(x) \, d\mu(x) \right)^2 \\
= \int_{\Omega} \int_{\Omega} (f(x)^2g(y)^2+f(y)^2g(x)^2-2f(x)g(x)f(y)g(y)) \, d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y) \\
= \int_{\Omega} \int_{\Omega} (f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x))^2 \, d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y) \geq 0, $$
since a square is nonnegative and the integral of a nonnegative number is nonnegative. Rearranging and taking the square root gives Cauchy–Schwarz for integrals. Equality holds when $ f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x)=0 $ $\mu$-almost everywhere, which needs $f(x)=cg(x)$. This is easily the most straightforward method of proof. This applies in particular to any interval $(a,b)$ with ordinary Lebesgue measure $dx$, whether $a,b$ are finite or not.

---

The inequality you give does not work even for the simplest case of a function with two values: $a_1b_1+a_2b_2$ has no particular relationship with $(a_1+a_2)(b_1+b_2)$, because the difference is
$$ (a_1+a_2)(b_1+b_2)-(a_1b_1+a_2b_2) = a_1b_2+a_2b_1, $$
which can have whatever value we like: $(1-1)(1-1)-|(1)(1)+(-1)(-1)| = -2<0 $, for example.