# Proof of Cauchy-Schwarz using double integral (Axler 8A.2)

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to understand 8A.2 of Axler's measure theory text:

> Prove that if $\mu$ is a measure and $f, g \in L^2(\mu)$, then
> $$
> ||f||^2||g||^2 - |\langle f,g \rangle|^2 = \frac 1 2 \int \int
> |f(x)g(y) - g(x)f(y)|^2 d\mu(y) d\mu(x) 
> $$

This intuitively makes sense, because if $f$ is a scalar multiple of $g$, the RHS equals zero.

This [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2312692/968391) seems to give an answer, but with very limited explanation. I reproduce the relevant part below.

\begin{align*}
& 2 \left ( \int f(x)^2 d\mu(x) \right ) \left ( \int g(x)^2 d\mu(x) \right ) - 2 \left( \int f(x) \overline{g(x)} d\mu(x) \right)^2 \\
\tag{1} &= \int \int (f(x)^2g(y)^2+f(y)^2g(x)^2-2f(x)g(x)f(y)g(y)) \, d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y) \\
&= \int \int (f(x)g(y)-f(y)g(x))^2 \, d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y)
\end{align*}

I don't understand $(1)$. More generally, this appears to suggest that for $f, g \in L^2(\mu)$,
$$
\tag{2} 2 \left ( \int f(x) d\mu(x) \right ) \left ( \int g(x) d\mu(x) \right ) = \int \int f(x)g(y) + f(y)g(x) d\mu(x) d\mu(y)
$$

Can someone provide a proof of $(2)$, or an explanation of the general principle behind $(1)$?

#### Update

Thanks for the quick feedback! Just attempted a proof.

Comment: Apply Fubini's Theorem to RHS.

Comment: Integrate iteratively! In case you are worrying, *don’t worry about Fubini*, this is not that type of “double” integral (I refer to $(2)$). If $(2)$ is supposed to be an integral over the product measure - rather than an iterative integral - then please clarify the notation

Comment: @geetha290krm Fubini’s theorem isn’t perfectly general, some hypotheses need to be met

Comment: This is a very nice proof! It's a generalisation of the classical proof with the Lagrange identity. It's good because it gives an estimation of how far you are from being an identity.

Comment: Thanks @GiuseppeNegro, just fixed spelling on title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Claim

Let $f, g \in L^2(\mu)$, with measure space $(X, S, \mu)$. Then
$$ 2 \left ( \int f(x) d\mu(x) \right ) \left ( \int g(x) d\mu(x) \right ) = \int \int f(x)g(y) + f(y)g(x) d\mu(x) d\mu(y) $$

#### Proof

\begin{align*}
& \int \int f(x)g(y) + f(y)g(x) d\mu(x) d\mu(y) \\ 
&= \int \left ( g(y) \int f(x)d\mu(x) + f(y) \int g(x) d\mu(x) \right ) d\mu(y) \\
&= \int f(x)d\mu(x) \int g(y) d\mu(y) + \int g(x) d\mu(x) \int f(y) d\mu(y) \\
&= 2 \left ( \int f(x) d\mu(x) \right ) \left ( \int g(x) d\mu(x) \right )
\end{align*}

Note that Fubini has been used here implicitly. The hypotheses of Fubini are satisfied here, because $f(x)g(y)$ is $S \otimes S$-measurable as the product of $L^2$ functions, and it's finite a.e.
$\square$